# Add toolbar button for plugin

Tags: pimcore

I know how to add a menu-item at the extras menu by using

```
pimcoreReady: function (params,broker){
    ...
    toolbar.extrasMenu.add(action);
```

But what im really looking for is to add a menu-item below the search button, here, Is it possible?
[image]

Also, I would like to show this icon only if the user has a certain permission assigned to him, is that possible without changing pimcores core?

Best Regards!
/J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
var user = pimcore.globalmanager.get("user");
var permissions = user.permissions;

// See what permissions are set - check the console in browser developer tools
console.log(user.permissions);

if (permissions.indexOf("objects") !== -1) {
  var navigationUl = Ext.get(Ext.query("#pimcore_navigation UL"));
  var newMenuItem = Ext.DomHelper.createDom('<li id="pimcore_menu_new-item" data-menu-tooltip="Your tooltip" class="pimcore_menu_item icon-fork"></li>');
  navigationUl.appendChild(newMenuItem);
  pimcore.helpers.initMenuTooltips();

  newMenuItem.onclick = function(){ 
    alert("test") 
  };
}
```